# Platform support. What is meant by "Windows Server 2012 R2 with Update (x64)"

Tags: web8.5

The documentation for SDL Web 8.5 specifies `Windows Server 2012 R2 with Update (x64)` as a supported platform.

Is it correct to suppose that the update in question is [KB2919355](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn645472(v=ws.11).aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think that is the one, indeed (blame MS for using such a non-descriptive name; why not "Update 1" or so?).

Without the Windows Update, the SDL Web 8.5 installer will fail when trying to install the .NET Framework 4.6.2.